# How do I refer to an element by the value of its index?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.3.

I have a group of checkboxes like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class="Product" value="5">
<input type='checkbox' class="Product" value="2">
<input type='checkbox' class="Product" value="3">
```

I am getting an element's index like this:

```
$(".Product").click(function() {
    // GET PRODUCT DETAILS
    var Idx = $(this).index(".Product");
)};
```

If you click on the first checkbox, the value of Idx should be zero. If the second box is clicked, the value of Idx should be one. If you click on the third box, Idx will be two.

Now let's say I want to uncheck the box that was just clicked using its index. How do I refer to an element by the value of its index?

```
$(".Product").click(function() {
    // GET PRODUCT DETAILS
    var Idx = $(this).index(".Product");
    alert('The index of the checkbox that was clicked was ' + Idx );

    // UNCHECK THE BOX THAT WAS JUST CHECKED -- NOT USING THIS
    $(".Product").index(Idx).attr("checked", false);


)};
```

This is the line that is incorrect and needs to be fixed:

```
    // UNCHECK THE BOX THAT WAS JUST CHECKED -- NOT USING THIS
    $(".Product").index(Idx).attr("checked", false);
```

Can you fix this?

Comment: At http://api.jquery.com/ if you type the word *"index"* into the search box at the top, the `.eq()` method becomes the second in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
$('.Product').eq(Idx).attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 6):

[.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) does this

```
 $(".Product").eq(Idx).attr("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

and you can use the selector version of eq as well:

```
$(".Product:eq("+Idx+")").attr("checked", false);
```

Comment: I sometimes forget that I can just fix small issues like that myself.

Comment: yea but the comment helps break me of my habit of not double checking before i post